# How can I be notified when a dispatch_async task is complete?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, asynchronous, grand-central-dispatch

I have a asynchronous task like so:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
     myAsyncMethodsHere;
});
```

Is there a way to be notified when the background task is complete?

Or to call a method upon completion?

I've read through the documentation and have looked into dispatch_after, but it seems to be more designed to dispatch the method after a certain length of time.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

**From the docs:**

COMPLETION CALLBACKS

Completion callbacks can be accomplished via nested calls to the dispatch_async() function. It is
important to remember to retain the destination queue before the first call to dispatch_async(), and to release that queue at the end of the completion callback to ensure the destination queue is not deallocated while the completion callback is pending.  For example:

```
 void
 async_read(object_t obj,
         void *where, size_t bytes,
         dispatch_queue_t destination_queue,
         void (^reply_block)(ssize_t r, int err))
 {
         // There are better ways of doing async I/O.
         // This is just an example of nested blocks.

         dispatch_retain(destination_queue);

         dispatch_async(obj->queue, ^{
                 ssize_t r = read(obj->fd, where, bytes);
                 int err = errno;

                 dispatch_async(destination_queue, ^{
                         reply_block(r, err);
                 });
                 dispatch_release(destination_queue);
         });
 }
```

[Source](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man3/dispatch_async.3.html)

Comment: hi.. I have one doubt.. according to the documentations: dispatch_async returns immediately, and then the block executes asynchronously in the background. My doubt is .. since we are using dispatch_release after call of inner dispatch_async, is it not going to release the destination_queue before executing the inner block on it?

Comment: possibly, it may be better to include the release inside of the dispatch_async callback like so:
 
 dispatch_async(destination_queue, ^{
                         reply_block(r, err);
                 dispatch_release(destination_queue);                   });

Comment: I believe that the queue will be retained at the creation of the block, not when it is executed.

Comment: The block instance is created at the time execution reaches the line it is declared.  When that happens, the queue is retained.  The subsequent `dispatch_release` will just release your handle on it.  The block will always have a handle on it.  Once the block goes away, so will the queue.